# Where is roles folder created on chef-server when a role is created on chef-ui

Tags: chef-infra

When a role is created using the chef web interface where is that role file created? (.rb or .json)

Comment: @MarkO'Connor can you please post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef server does not persist data as JSON on the server. It has an internal file store and Postgres database.

If you want to retrieve JSON use the knife download command. See:

- http://docs.getchef.com/knife_download.html